# Is it possible to assign system wide hotkey to show/hide app?

Tags: keyboard, automator, iterm

I'm trying to mimic iTerm2 feature. It has a feature to show/hide iTerm2 by a hotkey (eg. option + space).

[image]

When I press the hotkey, the app was shown. Is it possible to do the same to another app? I want to assign ctrl+space to show sublime text.

I have create an automator like this:

[image]

And assign a shortcut (ctrl+space) like this:

[image]

I have test the automator. It run well. But, the shortcut won't work.

Comment: Sometimes the shortcut does not work because the scripts expects text to be selected. Check the first module in your automator script, or select some text and try the shortcut then.

Comment: It's also got a big yellow triangle underneath with "Shortcut used by another application"

Comment: user495470's answer worked for me http://superuser.com/questions/339493/global-hotkey-to-show-hide-a-specific-app-in-os-x